# DotNetOpenId -- "This message has already been processed" Error

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm starting with OpenId using the dotnetopenid library and, so far, so good, but when I try to login, it shows me the following message:

> **This message has already been**
>   **processed. This could indicate a**
>   **replay attack in progress.**

The first time I used my app it failed and, after that, the above message it is always returned.

How can I "logout" the user that I'm using for testing or how can I can clear the request so I can login/logout?

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, a seely problem as usual...

I was calling the **GetResponse** more than once, and that got me error message.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your answers =)

Answer (score 0):

The replay attack message is usually because you clicked Refresh on the browser while the the URL in your browser still has a bunch of OpenID parameters in it.  Try clearing off everything after the ? mark, or just retype the URL and press enter.  If that doesn't work, then try adding a question mark to the URL and pressing enter.

How to log off?  DotNetOpenId defaults to using forms authentication, so you can sign the user off by calling FormsAuthentication.SignOut().

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of dotnetopenauth you can also get:

> This message has already been
>   processed. This could indicate a
>   replay attack in progress.

if your maxAuthenticationTime value is too low (which is obviously not related to the error in any way - but that is a different issue). I experienced this just today.

To increase this value, edit the config entry as shown at http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/configuration-options/ (I suggest setting to 0:10).