# DotNetOpenAuth: This message has already been processed. This could indicate a replay attack in progress

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to protect my WCF Service using DotNetOpenAuth's RelyingPartyLogic sample. I have Consumers authenticating working but when I go to make an Auhtorized Request against the Api I get the error **This message has already been processed**.  This could indicate a replay attack in progress." with the stack trace:

> at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage
>   message)    at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage
>   message)    at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequest(HttpRequestInfo
>   httpRequest)    at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.TryReadFromRequest[TRequest](HttpRequestInfo
>   httpRequest, TRequest& request)    at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ServiceProvider.ReadProtectedResourceAuthorization(HttpRequestInfo
>   request)    at
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ServiceProvider.ReadProtectedResourceAuthorization(HttpRequestMessageProperty
>   request, Uri requestUri)    at
>   RelyingPartyLogic.OAuthAuthorizationManager.CheckAccessCore(OperationContext
>   operationContext) in
>   D:\Code\Nodeler\Nodeler.RelyingPartyLogic\OAuthAuthorizationManager.cs:line
>   44    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess(OperationContext
>   operationContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess(OperationContext
>   operationContext, Message& message)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AuthorizationBehavior.Authorize(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)

The trace is as follows:

> 2011-04-02 19:16:12,414 (GMT-5) [16]
>   DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
>   - Sending message: AuthorizedTokenResponse 2011-04-02
>   19:16:15,362 (GMT-5) [16] INFO 
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel -
>   Scanning incoming request for
>   messages:
>   http://localhost:16468/Api/HelloWorld?oauth_token=7ix8k5NXN4NE1EXQWlHYE6klk7A%3D&oauth_consumer_key=f9fa91faa048434a86ab95681e9f732d&oauth_nonce=N7SPWJPl&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=HyNQvfk2OrP%2FnMFjLJdNih4c8N8%3D&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_timestamp=1301789775
>   2011-04-02 19:16:15,376 (GMT-5) [16]
>   DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
>   - Incoming request received: AccessProtectedResourceRequest
>   2011-04-02 19:16:15,377 (GMT-5) [16]
>   INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
>   - Processing incoming AccessProtectedResourceRequest (1.0)
>   message:  oauth_token:
>   7ix8k5NXN4NE1EXQWlHYE6klk7A=
>     oauth_consumer_key:
>   f9fa91faa048434a86ab95681e9f732d
>     oauth_nonce: N7SPWJPl
>     oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
>     oauth_signature:
>   HyNQvfk2OrP/nMFjLJdNih4c8N8=
>     oauth_version: 1.0  oauth_timestamp:
>   1301789775
>
> 2011-04-02 19:16:15,377 (GMT-5) [16]
>   DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Verifying incoming
>   AccessProtectedResourceRequest message
>   signature of:
>   HyNQvfk2OrP/nMFjLJdNih4c8N8=
>   2011-04-02 19:16:15,377 (GMT-5) [16]
>   DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
>   - Applying secrets to message to prepare for signing or signature
>   verification. 2011-04-02 19:16:15,423
>   (GMT-5) [16] DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Constructed signature base string:
>   GET&http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A16468%2FApi%2FHelloWorld&oauth_consumer_key%3Df9fa91faa048434a86ab95681e9f732d%26oauth_nonce%3DN7SPWJPl%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1301789775%26oauth_token%3D7ix8k5NXN4NE1EXQWlHYE6klk7A%253D%26oauth_version%3D1.0
>   2011-04-02 19:16:15,424 (GMT-5) [16]
>   DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Binding element
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElementChain
>   applied to message. 2011-04-02
>   19:16:15,424 (GMT-5) [16] DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Binding element
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement
>   applied to message. 2011-04-02
>   19:16:15,424 (GMT-5) [16] DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Binding element
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement
>   applied to message. 2011-04-02
>   19:16:15,424 (GMT-5) [16] DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Binding element
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthHttpMethodBindingElement
>   did not apply to message. 2011-04-02
>   19:16:15,528 (GMT-5) [16] DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Binding element
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.TokenHandlingBindingElement
>   did not apply to message. 2011-04-02
>   19:16:15,528 (GMT-5) [16] DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel -
>   After binding element processing, the
>   received
>   AccessProtectedResourceRequest (1.0)
>   message is:   oauth_token:
>   7ix8k5NXN4NE1EXQWlHYE6klk7A=
>     oauth_consumer_key:
>   f9fa91faa048434a86ab95681e9f732d
>     oauth_nonce: N7SPWJPl
>     oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
>     oauth_signature:
>   HyNQvfk2OrP/nMFjLJdNih4c8N8=
>     oauth_version: 1.0  oauth_timestamp:
>   1301789775
>
> 2011-04-02 19:16:15,816 (GMT-5) [5]
>   INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
>   - Scanning incoming request for messages:
>   http://localhost:16468/Api/HelloWorld?oauth_token=7ix8k5NXN4NE1EXQWlHYE6klk7A%3D&oauth_consumer_key=f9fa91faa048434a86ab95681e9f732d&oauth_nonce=N7SPWJPl&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=HyNQvfk2OrP%2FnMFjLJdNih4c8N8%3D&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_timestamp=1301789775
>   2011-04-02 19:16:15,826 (GMT-5) [5]
>   DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
>   - Incoming request received: AccessProtectedResourceRequest
>   2011-04-02 19:16:15,826 (GMT-5) [5]
>   INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
>   - Processing incoming AccessProtectedResourceRequest (1.0)
>   message:  oauth_token:
>   7ix8k5NXN4NE1EXQWlHYE6klk7A=
>     oauth_consumer_key:
>   f9fa91faa048434a86ab95681e9f732d
>     oauth_nonce: N7SPWJPl
>     oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
>     oauth_signature:
>   HyNQvfk2OrP/nMFjLJdNih4c8N8=
>     oauth_version: 1.0  oauth_timestamp:
>   1301789775
>
> 2011-04-02 19:16:15,826 (GMT-5) [5]
>   DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Verifying incoming
>   AccessProtectedResourceRequest message
>   signature of:
>   HyNQvfk2OrP/nMFjLJdNih4c8N8=
>   2011-04-02 19:16:15,826 (GMT-5) [5]
>   DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
>   - Applying secrets to message to prepare for signing or signature
>   verification. 2011-04-02 19:16:15,853
>   (GMT-5) [5] DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Constructed signature base string:
>   GET&http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A16468%2FApi%2FHelloWorld&oauth_consumer_key%3Df9fa91faa048434a86ab95681e9f732d%26oauth_nonce%3DN7SPWJPl%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1301789775%26oauth_token%3D7ix8k5NXN4NE1EXQWlHYE6klk7A%253D%26oauth_version%3D1.0
>   2011-04-02 19:16:15,853 (GMT-5) [5]
>   DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Binding element
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElementChain
>   applied to message. 2011-04-02
>   19:16:15,853 (GMT-5) [5] DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings -
>   Binding element
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement
>   applied to message. 2011-04-02
>   19:16:15,853 (GMT-5) [5] ERROR
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId - Replayed nonce
>   detected (N7SPWJPl 04/03/2011
>   00:16:15).  Rejecting message.

UPDATE: After some more digging the problem is that StandardExpirationBindingElement is being applied twice which causes the Nonce to be added to the NonceMemoryStore more then once. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Have you reviewed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727838/dotnetopenid-this-message-has-already-been-processed-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165525/dotnetopenid-this-message-has-already-been-processed-error-part-2 ?

Comment: Yes, I did see those. They helped a little but neither were the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OAuthAuthenticationModule` that ship with the project template is already "consuming" the nonce that is included with the OAuth-authorized request.  When your `OAuthAuthorizationManager` is also applied, it tries to consume the nonce a second time and thus is detected as a replay attack.  The first module is authorizing any incoming HTTP request at the ASP.NET level, whereas the second module is authorizing an incoming WCF request specifically (on top of the ASP.NET validation) so that WCF-style authorization is applied.  Exactly one should be applied -- one or the other but not both.

Answer (score 1):

I found the root issue. **OAuthAuthenticationModule** was also processing the request. Updating the **IsOAuthControllerRequest** function fixed it. I'm not sure if this is a proper fix or not but at this point I'm moving on. I'm not sure if it's just the nature or OAuth or if its DotNetOpenAuth itself but I haven't been this frustrated with programming for years.

```
private bool IsOAuthControllerRequest()
{
    return string.Equals(this.application.Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "/OAuth.ashx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || this.application.Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower().StartsWith("/api/");
}
```

Comment: OAuth requires that each signed request only be received once to protect against replay attacks.  Your conclusion that it was being processed by two modules is correct.  DotNetOpenAuth's project template that you're based on applies OAuth security checks on every incoming request by default.  Since you *also* applied it to WCF incoming messages, it was happening twice.  Disabling one or the other is the correct fix (picking the right one is up to the scenario).

Comment: Your modification of the `IsOAuthControllerRequest` is not correct though.  Now your method is lying.  You should probably change the code that calls this method to also opt-out for an additional case (your /api/ path).  Alternatively, just disable the OAuthAuthenticationModule altogether since your WCF API is protected on its own.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Didn't realize they were doing basically the same thing. I removed the OAuthAuthorizationManager and updated the web.config to "protect" the Api using FormsAuthentication and it's working now without the work around. If you want to write that as an answer I can accept it as correct. ;) Thanks for your help.